# Spring boot i18n for multiple users

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, internationalization, angular-i18n

Currently, I am using Spring i18n for internationalization in my application. The application will have around 5 different languages (may be changed later).

To show labels according to the language selected by the user, the frontend will use the keys that are the same that of the keys from **messages.properties** in the backend.

The frontend will call REST API with the keys they need in order to show on the basis of the locale they pass. The API looks like:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/internationalization")
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> translate(@RequestBody List<String> keys) {
    Map<String, String> translatedValues = new HashMap<>();
    keys.forEach(k -> {
        translatedValues.put(k, this.messageSource.getMessage(k, null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()));
    });
    return ResponseEntity.ok(translatedValues);
}
```

Everything was working fine. All of a sudden, I got some additional requirements that are too confusing to me. The requirement is

Let's say **User-1** enters some values in the Chinese language which will be saved as is in the database. Now, is it possible for **User-2** who has the French language as the default language to see those contents entered by **User-1** in the French language? Likewise, I have to support it for five different languages for now.

How do I accommodate this kind of requirement?

I know Google Translation provides API for translation but how efficient will it be? Please, share your experience.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Labels is different from data, from the description on the answer i think the new requirement is about the data, which means you will something to translate the data before sending them to the UI, this might still remain simple as long as you dont also need to edit the translated data, if you will be editing the data you should be aware that you might lose some information during multiple translations. more context in the question will help, like an example or what exactly the data you expect you will need to translate.